# UIImageView won't resize properly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I have an image which I want to scale accordingly to a certain percentage which I have done this way:

```
CGRect frame = _image.frame;
frame.size.height = frame.size.height * 0.4 //0.4 is actually a float
_image.frame = frame;
```

This scales the image properly, although the origin is the center, so the image shrinks in to the middle. When I do the same thing in Interface Builder, I can set the origin to down in the middle and when I change the size of the height it shrinks perfectly only in length.
How can I do that programmatically. I tried anchorPoint but that screws everything up, I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `contentMode` property of `UIImageView` with `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` or some other value, by `Interface Builder` or program, to meet your scale style.